# UISlider TouchUpInside Not firing at ends of slider

Tags: events, action, uislider

My slider sets a flag in ValueChanged and then resets it in TouchUpInside.  However, when I touch the handle and slide it all the way to the end of the slider, the TouchUpInside event doesn't get fired (and hence my flag doesn't get reset).

Do I need to handle another UISlider action when I slide the handle to the end of the slider?  I tried TouchCancel thinking that maybe it was getting cancelled when my finger moved past the end of the slider bar, but that didn't work.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas on this one?  Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, I needed to use the TouchUpOutside action/event.